# update DB function clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

i'm trying to build a function similar to SQL :

```
UPDATE Persons SET Address=Martin20, City=Miami WHERE LastName=Darmon AND FirstName=Gilad
```

i have parsed the SET and Where into a map and List.

 and now i want to update the table i have. however i'm getting an error

```
Exception in thread "main" setMap #<Ref@6bad186f: [:Address Martin20 :City Miami]>
whereList #{0}
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
    at clojure.lang.APersistentMap$KeySeq.first(APersistentMap.java:132)
    at clojure.lang.RT.first(RT.java:559)
    at clojure.core$first.invoke(core.clj:55)
    at ClojureSQL$UpdateRecord.invoke(project.clj:205)
    at ClojureSQL$UpdateTable.invoke(project.clj:253)
    at ClojureSQL$Execute.invoke(project.clj:285)
    at ClojureSQL$eval1340.invoke(project.clj:312)
```

this is the function to setup the parameters for the Update function:

```
;UpdateTable function
(defn UpdateTable [updateQuery]
  "The UPDATE statement is used to update existing records in a table"
  (println "UPDATE ")
  (let [SpecificGetTableName (CreateGetTableNameFunc #"UPDATE ([_0-9a-zA-Z]+)") 
        tableName (SpecificGetTableName updateQuery)
        whereList (ListRecordsMatchConditions updateQuery tableName)        ; return the row numbers in which we need to update 
        setMap    (GetValuesFromSetCommand updateQuery)]
    (UpdateRecord tableName whereList setMap)
  )
)
```

the bug is in the doseq function:

```
;update specific table records (from whereList) with new values (from setMap)
(defn UpdateRecord [tableName whereList setMap]
  "Insert values into table in order of keys / columns"
  (println "setMap" setMap)
  (println "whereList" whereList)
  (let [tableRef (get (deref dataBase) tableName)]        
    (doseq [curKey (keys @setMap) i whereList]         ; <-here is the BUG

       (dosync (alter (tableRef curKey) assoc i val))  ; perfrom thread safe insert of value to column
    )
    (println tableRef) 
  )
)
```

Comment: What is the output of the two `println`s before the error?

Comment: @sgarrett setMap #<Ref@6bad186f: [:Address Martin20 :City Miami]>
whereList #{0}

Comment: What does the "@" do in the following `(doseq [curKey (keys @setMap) i whereList]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setMap` ref wraps a vector, not a map.  The `keys` function returns a seq of keys from a map, not a vector.  You would need to change setMap to wrap a map:

```
(ref {:Address "Martin20" :City "Miami"})
```